# How to set daily,weakly,monthly,yearly recurrence pattern in calendar(.pst file) using aspose.email for java(jar file)

Tags: java, aspose

I am mac os x developer.I have to create .pst file on mac os x machine using java(eclipse).I am using aspose third party jar file (aspose.email for java).But problem with setting monthly recurrence pattern in calendar.

But I found problem is that it shows exception-
 
Duration can't be more than period of recurrence.

****** source code ********

java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

```
      calendar.set(2015, java.util.Calendar.JANUARY, 1,0,0,0);

      Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

      calendar.set(2016, java.util.Calendar.MARCH, 1,0,0,0);

      Date endDate = calendar.getTime();
```

MapiCalendarEventRecurrence f_reccurence = new MapiCalendarEventRecurrence();

```
  f_reccurence.setRecurrencePattern(new MapiCalendarWeeklyRecurrencePattern());

  f_reccurence.getRecurrencePattern().setPatternType(MapiCalendarRecurrencePatternType.Week);

  f_reccurence.getRecurrencePattern().setOccurrenceCount(3);

 

  f_reccurence.getRecurrencePattern().setPeriod(2);

  f_reccurence.getRecurrencePattern().setEndType(MapiCalendarRecurrenceEndType.NeverEnd);

 

  mapiWeakly = new MapiCalendar("This is Location", "This is Weekly", "This is description",startDate, endDate);

  mapiWeakly.setLocation("This is location");

  mapiWeakly.setRecurrence(f_reccurence);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

We have already investigated this issue posted by you in Aspose.Email forum and feedback has been shared with you in forum. This is actually an issue with the API's recurrence functionality. For further assistance, please follow your [thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/704692/how-to-set-daily-weakly-monthly-yearly-recurrence-pattern-in-calendar-.pst-file-using-aspose.email.aspx) in Aspose.Email forum.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.